# display change ruins opacity transition

Tags: html, css, transition, display

I want to have a sub-menu that is invisible and turns to visible when the parent menu in hower. Note that I don't want the sub-menu to become visible when the mouse goes over the place the sub-menu should be.
In this case i want the sub-menus aaaa,bbbb,cccc and dddd to become visible when the mouse goes over menu "menu".
But i can't achieve it since the change in display ruins the transitions.
Here is my html:

```
<body>
    <nav class="gnb" dir="rtl">
        <ul class="gnb">
            <li class="gnb"> <a class="gnb" href="../products/products.html">menu</a>

                <ul class="sub-constructibles">
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">aaaa</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">bbbb</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">cccc</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">dddd</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

And here is my css:

```
* {
    transition: all .4s;
}
nav.gnb {
    background-color: #0f7f07;
}
li.gnb {
    display:inline-block;
}
li.gnb:hover {
    background-color: #20ca05;
}
ul.sub-constructibles {
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #20ca05;
}
li.gnb:hover ul.sub-constructibles {
    opacity:.9;
    visibility:visible;
}
a.gnb {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e4h0bccy/

i also have tried changing visibility instead of display but it doesn't work bc the sub-menus become visible also when the mouse goes on their prior place.

Comment: I believe you can't do that on css but in js you can for sure

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. Never have duplicate IDs.

Comment: @MrLister thanks!i fixed it, but that wasn't the problem indeed since no IDs were used in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is to set `display: block` and `visibility: hidden` to the submenu. Take a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/e4h0bccy/2/

```
ul.sub-constructibles {
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #20ca05;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

With the opacity sets as zero, you have no problem because the menu is not visible till you have hovered.

Snippet:

```css
* {
    transition: all .4s;
}
nav.gnb {
    background-color: #0f7f07;
}
li.gnb {
    display:inline-block;
}
li.gnb:hover {
    background-color: #20ca05;
}
ul.sub-constructibles {
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #20ca05;
    visibility: hidden;
}
li.gnb:hover ul.sub-constructibles {
    display:block;
    opacity:.9;
    visibility: visible;
}
a.gnb {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="gnb" dir="rtl">
        <ul class="gnb">
            <li class="gnb" id="constructibles"> <a class="gnb" id="constructibles" href="../products/products.html">menu</a>

                <ul class="sub-constructibles">
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">aaaa</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">bbbb</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">cccc</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="gnb"><a class="gnb" href="#">dddd</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes but when the cursor goes over its place, it shows up while it shouldn't!

Comment: It only displays if you hover into `Menu` word

Comment: Please, test the answers before make a judgement.